# How to display all lines from a textpad into a list. Python 3 error

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

What I want to achieve is trying to open a text file with text. The format of the text is something like this:

```
Bear
Car
Plant
```

Etc. Now the code that I have now:

```
try:
    with open(info) as information:
        for line in information.readlines():
            line = line.split()
except IOError as error:
    print("Failed to open. Try again.")
```

Only prints out the last line in a list. What I want to do is print out ALL the words in the list.

So for the example above when I print(line) it prints `['Plant']` but I want `['Bear','Car','Plant']`.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to split, you need to *strip* (to remove the newline) using [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), then add the result to a list:

```
lines = []
with open(info) as information:
    for line in information:
        lines.append(line.strip())
```

Note that the `file.readlines()` call is not needed at all; just iterating over the file is enough.

You can do this in one go by reading the whole file and using [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
with open(info) as information:
    lines = information.read().splitlines()
```

or you can use iteration still, in a list comprehension:

```
with open(info) as information:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in information]
```

Answer (score 0):

`readlines` reads file as list

```
try:
    with open(info) as information:
        lines =  information.readlines()
except IOError as error:
    print("Failed to open. Try again.")
```

you can also use `list`:

```
try:
    with open(info) as information:
        lines = list(information)
except IOError as error:
    print("Failed to open. Try again.")
```